# Docker Container Not Starting for create docker file

Tags: docker, dockerfile

AM completely new to Docker, now am trying to create a container for tomact from ubuntu base image & written a docker file acoding to it:

```
From ubuntu
RUN apt-get update -y && apt-get upgrade -y
RUN apt-get install wget -y
RUN apt-get install  openjdk-8-jdk -y
RUN mkdir /usr/local/tomcat
RUN wget https://mirrors.estointernet.in/apache/tomcat/tomcat-8/v8.5.61/bin/apache-tomcat-8.5.61.tar.gz
RUN tar xvzf apache-tomcat-8.5.61.tar.gz
RUN mv apache-tomcat-8.5.61 /usr/local/tomcat/
#MD ./usr/local/tomcat/apache-tomcat-8.5.61/bin/catlina.sh run
EXPOSE 8080
RUN /usr/local/tomcat/apache-tomcat-8.5.61/bin/catlina.sh run
```

Created Docker image for the respective docker file using:
`docker build -t [filename] .` 
Tried to start the container using: `docker run -itd --name my-con -p 8080:8080` 
but the container is not starting & the container is listed in stopped container
Cn any one help me fixing this issue
Thanks.

Comment: There's probably extra things you have to install onto the ubuntu base. I have no idea what these are as you've not provided any logs.

I will say, one nice thing about docker you should take advantage of is all the remade docker images

https://hub.docker.com/_/tomcat

Comment: my organisation wants me to create own tomcat image

Comment: What is the exit code? Do you have any logs?

Comment: hey, i solved it, we should use cmd command in last line & to start cmd command:
CMD ["/usr/local/tomcat/bin/catalina.sh","run"]

Answer (score 0):

try this in last line:
CMD ["/usr/local/tomcat/bin/catalina.sh","run"]